# how to resolve this "inf" problem with python code

Tags: python

i have a problem with this python code for inverting a Number
**like Nb = 358 ---> inv = 853**
but in the end **i got 'inf' msg** from the prog , and its runs normally in C language

```
def envers(Nb):
 inv = 0
 cond = True
 while cond:
    s = Nb % 10
    inv = (inv*10)+ s
    Nb = Nb/10
    if Nb == 0:
        cond = False
 return inv

data = int(input("give num"))
res = envers(data)
print(res)
```

Comment: this could be due to floating point `/` rather than integer `//` division as you might expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation for a numerical approach:

```
def envers(Nb):
    out = 0
    while Nb>0:
        Nb, r = divmod(Nb, 10)
        out = 10*out + r
    return out


envers(1234)
# 4321

envers(358)
# 853

envers(1020)
# 201
```

Without [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
def envers(Nb):
    out = 0
    while Nb>0:
        r = Nb % 10
        Nb //= 10
        out = 10*out + r
    return out
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely *much* easier to do via string manipulation, which has a friendly and simple syntax (which are a major reason to choose to use Python)

```py
>>> int(input("enter a number to reverse: ")[::-1])
enter a number to reverse: 1234
4321
```

How this works

- `input()` returns a string
- strings are iterable and `[::-1]` is used to reverse it
- finally convert to an `int`

Add error checking to taste (for example to to ensure you really received a number)

Answer (score 1):

When you set

`Nb = Nb / 10`

Nb becomes a float (say 1 -> 0.1) and will be able to keep being divided until it reaches a certain limit.

By that point, your inv value will reach python's limits and become 'inf'.

Replacing this line with

`Nb = Nb // 10`

using Python's builtin integer division will fix the issue.